# Reset network configuration in ubuntu 12.04

Tags: 12.04, network-manager, pppoe

My DSL internet did not connect by network-manager! So I tried to use `sudo pppoeconf` and my laptop connect to internet successfully. After that my problems are started! First of all network-manager does not run in start up! I try `sudo nm-applet` and get

```
** (nm-applet:4966): WARNING **: Could not initialize NMClient /org/freedesktop/NetworkManager: The name org.freedesktop.NetworkManager was not provided by any .service files
** Message: applet now removed from the notification area

** (nm-applet:4966): WARNING **: Failed to register as an agent: (2) The name org.freedesktop.NetworkManager was not provided by any .service files
** Message: using fallback from indicator to GtkStatusIcon
** Message: Starting applet secret agent because GNOME Shell disappeared

** (nm-applet:4966): WARNING **: Failed to register as an agent: (2) The name org.freedesktop.NetworkManager was not provided by any .service files
```

and I try `sudo /etc/init.d/networking start`, which I gain

```
Rather than invoking init scripts through /etc/init.d, use the service(8) utility, e.g. service networking start
Since the script you are attempting to invoke has been converted to an Upstart job, you may also use the start(8) utility, e.g. start networking
```

any after I try `service networking start`

```
start: Rejected send message, 1 matched rules; type="method_call", sender=":1.71" (uid=1000 pid=3624 comm="start networking ") interface="com.ubuntu.Upstart0_6.Job" member="Start" error name="(unset)" requested_reply="0" destination="com.ubuntu.Upstart" (uid=0 pid=1 comm="/sbin/init")
```

This is my `/etc/ppp/peers/dsl-provider`

```
noipdefault
usepeerdns
hide-password
lcp-echo-interval 20
lcp-echo-failure 3
connect /bin/true
noauth
persist
mtu 1485
noaccomp
default-asyncmap
plugin rp-pppoe.so eth0
user "511"
```

This is my `/etc/network/interfaces`

```
auto lo
iface lo inet loopback

auto eth0
iface eth0 inet dhcp
# manual

auto dsl-provider
iface dsl-provider inet ppp
provider dsl-provider
```

and this is my `/etc/NetworkManager/NetworkManager.conf`

```
[main]
plugins=ifupdown,keyfile
dns=dnsmasq

[ifupdown]
managed=false
```

The problem is to reverse this process! And bring back `nm-applet` to my desktop again!

I need NetworkManager to share my DSL internet through my modem.

So I have two question: First, Is there any way that I can reconfigure my network like before running `sudo pppoeconf`? Second, if there is not any way to bring NetworkManager to my desktop, how can I share my internet without NetworkManager?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

The NetworkManager daemon runs with elevated privileges. nm-applet is supposed to run with user privileges. Don't start it with `sudo`.

It is possible that through misuse of `sudo` you have messed up the ownerships and permissions of relevant files on your filesystem.

Note that `pppoeconf` is not meant to be used along with NetworkManager. If you run Ubuntu Desktop you normally use NetworkManager (only). If you run Ubuntu Server you normally use `ifup` and possibly things like `pppoeconf` along with it.

Comment: I'm not quite sure if this is the cause. I have had similar issues with 3 computers on the same OS. In my case it happened after an update. Not quite sure.